# Limiting ACF's "acf/validate_save_post" action from a front-end form

Tags: javascript, php, validation, advanced-custom-fields

I am using ACF's `acf/validate_save_post` action hook to validate a serial number  from a front-end form with a 3rd party API before the form submits and saves to a post type.

If the call to the 3rd party API returns an error I am using this action hook to display validation errors using the `acf_add_validation_error()` function.

Due to the `acf/validation_save_post` action hook being called when a post is published (and before, when doing the JS validation), the serial number ends up being validated 3 times. This ends up locking the user out due to limits set on the API side.

Is there a way to lock the action hook out from running when a post is published and only have it run when it is doing the JS validation?

I have tried using `wp_doing_ajax()` in an `if` statement but I think all the work is done via AJAX anyway, unless I am wrong on that. It still appears to run more than once while using `wp_doing_ajax()` anyway so maybe there is another solution out there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone finds this in the future, the solution to the issue is to check if this is an AJAX request via `wp_doing_ajax()`. This will stop validation while publishing the post via the admin or the `acf/save_post` action hook.